# Andengine scene loop

Tags: android, andengine

When i move a sprite outside the scene, it dissappear. Is it possible that the sprite enter other side of the scene at the samet time.

For example when the sprite is moved to right side through x direction out of the scene enough, disappeared part of the sprite will appear scene's left side.

Comment: Kindly add some code to increase the understanding of the problem.

Comment: Sorry, i can not explain my question bu adding some codes, but i try to explain more clearly. I edited my question. Sorry for my imperfect english.

Comment: Do you need to show it partially gone? I mean that at some point its half is visible on the left side and half is visible on the right side of the screen?

Comment: Yes this is what i need.

Comment: I think that it is not possible, at least I do not recall any function like that at all, but what I would do is to make a copy of your sprite and put that copy on the other side of the screen. When your real sprite dissapears move it under your copy-sprite and then destroy your copy. It might be easy for simple sprites and a bit more difficult for animated or complex sprites... Anyway maybe this idea will help you.

Comment: Of course this is possible, why shouldn't it? The easiest solution I think of now is to just override the onManagedDraw method and draw the sprite a second time on the other side of the screen. In that way it works for every sprite/animated sprite/complex entity and without copying anything. Regarding copying objects: Don't do that, it will result in stuttering. Try to use an object-pool and reuse as many objects as you can. Have a look at the genericpool class that comes with AndEngine!